# How to plot two columns of "Time" that is Start_time and End_Time of a data frame in R

Tags: r, plot

**I am newbie to R programming** and trying to learn some basic plotting. I have a couple of questions

My data frame looks like this

```
EVENT_TYPE   DATE           TIME_START    TIME_END
event A      9/18/2014      14:47:01      16:53:07
event B      9/18/2014      15:52:16      17:08:30
event A      9/18/2014      16:26:19      16:53:58
event C      9/20/2014      19:25:51      19:25:51
event B      9/23/2014       3:40:39       4:38:07
event D      9/25/2014       8:15:40       8:59:40
```

**Ques 1.** I want to plot data from 9/18/2014 to 9/23/2014. How do I select a DATE range in R?

**Ques 2.** I want to plot EVENT_TYPE on y-axis and DATE(or a month column) on x-axis with the                    "TIME_START" and "TIME_END" plotted on graph so that I can have a look at the comparison between events.

I searched for this kind of question but did not got any answer to it.

**Any kind of help is very much appreciated. Kindly help me in learning R.**

Comment: You just want the words for EVENT_TYPE values to march across the plot area at the same level?

Comment: I want to display Event A, Event B, Event C, Event D on the Y-axis and Date Range (9/18/2014 to 9/23/2014) that is 9/18/2014 , 9/19/2014, 9/20/2014, 9/21/2014, 9/22/2014, 9/23/2014 on the X-Axis. For Example, I want to show that Event A started 14:47 on 9/18/2014 and ended at 16:53.

Comment: Be aware that if you plot these all on one plot, your lines will look very thin because each event is only 1 or 2 hours, but your x axis spans multiple *days*.

Answer (score 2):

First convert your start and end times to date-times in R:

```
x <- transform(x,
               start=as.POSIXct(paste(DATE, TIME_START), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'),
               end=as.POSIXct(paste(DATE, TIME_END), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Then you could use ggplot and draw a rectangle for each event on the timeline:

- x axis is datetime
- draw a rectangle from start to end of each event
- the reason for the custom `y` and `yend` is so that two overlapping
  events of the same type (e.g. the two event A on 9/18/2014) appear
  visually separate from each other. (I imagine you can do something similar with say `geom_bar()` and `position="jitter"` but I don't know how).
- the reason for ordering the `y` is simply to group similar events together on the Y axis, if you don't want it just use `1:nrow(x)` instead for your `y`.
- the `scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)` is just to suppress the y numbers. You could customise them as you wish.

Giving:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(transform(x, y=order(EVENT_TYPE, start)),
       aes(x=start, xend=end, y=y, yend=y, col=EVENT_TYPE)) +
  geom_segment(size=3) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)
```

[image]

As mentioned since your x axis is very large (spans multiple days) and each event only lasts 1-2 hours, you can barely see the bar for each event. You will have to think about how you wish to sensibly display your data, but this is not the point of the question. As an example if you just look at the first 3 events it is much clearer:

```
x2 <- x[1:3,]
ggplot(transform(x2, y=order(EVENT_TYPE, start)),
       aes(x=start, xend=end, y=y, yend=y, col=EVENT_TYPE)) +
  geom_segment(size=3) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question. If I want to give a Date range, I mean to say I want to plot data between two say 1st May 2015 to 1st June 2015, then how do I go with it in R?   
In SQL, I do it like 
where x BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015-05-01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
and TO_DATE ('2015-06-01', 'yyyy/mm/dd');

Comment: You could subset your dataframe before plotting, e.g. `subset(x, start >= as.POSIXct('2015-05-01 00:00:00') & end <= as.POSIXct('2015-06-01 23:59:59'))`, or simply limit your x axis when you plot e.g. add `+ scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct(...), as.POSIXct(...)))` to your `ggplot`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. It worked for me. But now I am facing another problem ... I am not able to see time intervals on the Y-axis, also I am not able to label the y-axis properly. It is showing labelled as only "Y" on the y-axis. 

There are in all 1000+ records in my dataset ranging from 2014 to 2015 . I am trying to plot those.

Comment: What do you want to show on the Y axis? As mentioned, I explicitly added `scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)` to suppress the Y axis as it was meaningless numbers. See `?scale_y_discrete` and work out what you want to show on the Y axis, and then provide the `labels` (and possibly `breaks`) arguments to put the labels on.

Comment: Thank you very very much @mathematical.coffee. It worked for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please help me in one more problem. 
I am trying to split the time into intervals says 15mins, 30min or 1 hour. (for ex. 00:30:00, 01:00:00, 01:30:00 .... OR 01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00 ) Can you please help me know how should I go with it. 

I am using 

ggplot(transform_time, aes(x = transform_time$TIME_START, y=transform_time$TIME_END, col=EVENT_TYPE)) + geom_line(size = 1)  + scale_x_datetime(limits = c(as.POSIXct("2014-05-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-05-31 23:59:59"))) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:31, limits=c(0,31))